# how to add 1 in last item of array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am solving one problem .but getting correct output for `small array` but my solution fail when array size is large

solution

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} digits
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var plusOne = function(digits) {

    let str = parseInt(digits.join(''))+1+''
    return str.split('')
};
```

**Question**
The digits are stored such that the most significant digit is at the head of the list, and each element in the array contain a single digit.

You may assume the integer does not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

```
Example 1:

Input: [1,2,3]
Output: [1,2,4]
Explanation: The array represents the integer 123.

Example 2:

Input: [4,3,2,1]
Output: [4,3,2,2]
Explanation: The array represents the integer 4321.
```

above cases are `passed`

failed cases

```
Input
[6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3]
Output
[6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,0,0,0]
Expected
[6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> let str = parseInt(digits.join(''))+1+''
> ```

With too many array elements, you are simply creating a number that is outside of the integer range here.

An implicit conversion to a float has to happen, and with that you get the inherent loss of precision - which then leads to several zeros in those places at the end, when you reverse the process.

---

Access the last array element specifically, and add 1 to the value. But if that last element had the value 9 already, you will of course have to repeat that same process for the previous one … basic application of “carry the one”.

```
var input = [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,9];

var output = [];

// loop over input array in reverse order
for(var i=input.length-1, toadd = 1; i>-1; --i) { 
  // add value `toadd` to current digit
  var incremented = input[i] + toadd;
  if(incremented < 10) {
    output.unshift(incremented); // add to front of output array
    toadd = 0; // reset toadd for all following digits, if we had no overflow
  }
  else {
    output.unshift(0); // overflow occurred, so we add 0 to front of array instead
  }
}

console.log(output)
```

This does take an “overflow” for `9` digits at the end into account; it does not handle the case when *all* digits are 9 though, if you need to handle that edge case as well, please implement that yourself.

Comment: any other solution..bettter way ?

Comment: better way to acheive this

Comment: Access the last array element specifically, and add 1 to the value. But if that last element had the value `9` already, you will of course have to repeat that same process for the previous one … basic application of “carry the one”.

Comment: ok can you please share code

Comment: See edit for a simple way how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
var arr = [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3,9,9]

function plusOne(index){
  if( index < 0 ) return ; // Base case
  if(arr[index] === 9){
      arr[index] = 0;
      plusOne(index-1); // For carry ahead
   }else{
       arr[index] +=  1
   }
}

plusOne(arr.length-1) // start with last digit
```

Answer (score 0):

This one recursively checks the last digits:

```js
const test1 = [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3]
const test2 = [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,9]

const plusOne = function(digits) {
    if(digits[digits.length - 1] === 9){
        digits = [...plusOne(digits.slice(0, -1)), 0]
    }else{
        digits[digits.length - 1]++
    }

    return digits;
};

console.log(plusOne(test1));
console.log(plusOne(test2));
```